# Build issue on server with same maven,java, db, properties configuration

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2

We have two servers.On both server java and maven version is same.

```
$> mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-8)
Java version: 1.7.0_25
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.2.0-40-virtual" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"
```

We are using git repository for version control.

Now the problem we are facing is:
If we build code on server 1 using mvn , war file gets created and runs without any issue in tomcat.
If we build code on server 2 using mvn with same git repository code, war file gets created and everything works fine except null pointer exception in one function.

```
Failed to disconnect: java.lang.NullPointerException null
     at com.intuit.ia.connection.PlatformHttpClient.disconnect(PlatformHttpClient.java:80)
     at com.intuit.ia.connection.IAPlatformClient.disconnect(IAPlatformClient.java:40)
```

if we push war file created on server 1 to server 2 that also works fine.but war file created on server 2 does not work on both server 1 and 2.

So  with same mvn version,java version.code base, db and properties configuration war file created on server 1 works on both servers but war file created on server 2 doesn't work on any server.

Earlier everything was working fine but since last 2 days this issue has occurred.
I guess there is some issue in building the war file but unable to find the exact problem.

Comment: first compare the unpacked war files from both servers with each other? Differences? Same jars contained? Same versions ?

Comment: yes both wars has same jar versions.Directory size of both exploded war is also same.

Comment: If both wars exactly the same it can't be a problem with the build. Have you also checked configuration files etc. binary comparsion? The size of directories is not enough, cause the aggregation of files could be same but the size on each file can be different. Using the same java versions (JDK) on each server to build? openjdk vs. oracle java etc. ?